# How to approach this algebraic problem

Tags: problem-solving

[image]

I have no idea how to approach this problem apart from expanding the whole thing out which creates more mess. And I am sure there is a easy trick. I think it is because I lack experience on such problems to spot the pattern.

Comment: Can you prove $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\ge3abc$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x,y,z>0$, then AM-GM inequality says
$$\frac{x+y+z}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{xyz}.$$
Let $x=a^2b, y=b^2c, z=c^2a$, then you get
$$\frac{a^2b+b^2c+c^2a}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{a^3b^3c^3}=abc$$
Now try with the other expression.